# "Most historians believe that Hitler came up with this explanation in hindsight. ...."

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

I am struggling to understand what the bolded sentences in the following paragraph mean:

> The origin of Hitler's hatred of Jews is not clear. In Mein Kampf, he
> described his development into an antisemite as the result of a long,
> personal struggle. Supposedly, his aversion to everything Jewish came
> to fruition when he was living and working as a painter in Vienna
> (1908-1913). **Most historians believe that Hitler came up with this
> explanation in hindsight. He would have used it to assure people who
> were not yet convinced of his ideas that they would eventually see the
> light.**

What does "came up with this explanation in hindsight" mean? Does it mean Hitler reflected on his past thoughts and experiences about Jewish people to decide he was an antisemite? Moreover, which explanation is the author referring to?

> He would have used it to assure people who were not yet convinced of
> his ideas that they would eventually see the light.

What is "it" in the above sentence? Does "it" refer to the justification for his antisemitic feelings? What does "would have" mean? Does it mean Hitler **wanted to but did not yet** explain to people his reasoning for the hatred of Jews?

Source: https://www.annefrank.org/en/anne-frank/go-in-depth/why-did-hitler-hate-jews/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Came up with this explanation in hindsight" means that he did not *really* develop his anti-Semitic feelings while he was living in Vienna. He said that he did, but this was not really true.

In "He would have used **it** to assure people who were not yet convinced," the pronoun **it** refers back to the closest preceding non-pronoun noun: **explanation**. He would have used *this explanation*—the explanation "I developed my anti-Semitic views while living in Vienna"—to assure people who were not yet convinced that they would become convinced.

Comment: Thank you for the response. _to assure people who were not yet convinced that they would become convinced._ Convinced of what? Do you mean they would be convinced of what he was preaching?

Comment: Convinced 'of his ideas', as it says in the passage - meaning his anti-Semitic ideas.

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: _to assure people who were not yet convinced that they would become convinced_. This still does not make sense to me. What would he say to people? Would he say "My experiences in Vienna have convinced me that Jews are our enemies. You all may not feel the same way but about Jews YET but sooner or later, you will."?

Comment: Yes, that's the general idea.

Comment: @KateBunting Oh ok. Thank you for the response.

Comment: _"Came up with this explanation in hindsight" means that he did not really develop his anti-Semitic feelings while he was living in Vienna. He said that he did, but this was not really true._ Is the explanation just that he became an antisemite in Vienna? Shouldn't the explanation be that "I struggled with antisemitic feelings throughout my life (as described in Mein Kampf) but these feelings became entrenched in me when I was living in Vienna."? Why did you leave out the Mein Kampf part in your answer?

Comment: The passage says that historians suspect that Hitler was always prejudiced against Jews; he only claimed (in _Mein Kampf_) to have developed his ideas gradually.

Comment: @KateBunting My focus was on **Hilter's explanation** in the sentence _Most historians believe that Hitler came up with this explanation in hindsight._. randomhead wrote Hitler's explanation was `I developed my anti-Semitic views while living in Vienna..` while I think his explanation was `I struggled with antisemitic feelings throughout my life (as described in Mein Kampf) but these feelings became entrenched in me when I was living in Vienna.`

Comment: _....means that he did not really develop his anti-Semitic feelings while he was living in Vienna. He said that he did, but this was not really true._ How do you know his claim was not true?

Comment: @a_sid: I don't know that his claim was not true, but the author of the passage thinks his claim was not true. That's what "came up with this explanation in hindsight" means: He had an aversion to Jewish people, and **made up** ("came up with") an explanation that he developed this aversion while living in Vienna.

Comment: @randomhead Thank you for the response.